# Estimating effort to port code from Matlab to Octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I just read a fascinating paper: http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~ckemp/Papers/kempt08.pdf

In my opinion it takes the whole area of machine learning to a completely new level because it flexibly discovers the structure of data (and doesn't only try to find a best fit for an existing structure).

The code is also available: http://www.psy.cmu.edu/~ckemp/code/formdiscovery.html

I tried to do a few experiments of my own - but unfortunately I don't possess Matlab. I tried it with Octave but it only produced all kinds of error messages, which I don't understand (I am no expert on these programs).

Could anybody perhaps have a quick look if these problems can be solved easily (or at all)? Perhaps the solution will be an easy one (this is my hope after all).

This would really be a big help! I am very much looking forward to trying a few data sets of my own.

Comment: Could you perhaps post the error messages?

Comment: @Jonas: I don't know if this is helpful but here they are: Der Befehl "which" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
  demo_chain_feat chain
error: display: not defined for class "char"
error: called from:
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\3.2.4\m\general\display.m at line 36, column 3
error:   runmodel.m at line 17, column 1
error:   masterrun.m at line 64, column 38

Comment: @vonjd I didn't run through all code exceptions, but from the very few ones I checked, it is possible to trace back all errors (yes, one by one :-) and get it work with Octave, or close to. For example, the first error you reported has to do with `display` method not defined for a `char`acter variable. Replace with `disp` and it works. Then, the program will throw another error when trying to create subdirectories... I'm afraid I cannot help more, but I do think spending some time solving those compatibility bugs would be profitable to your understanding of Octave and this particular toolbox.

Comment: @chl: in the main file masterrun.m there is no "display", only "disp" and I thought the display.m is an own file of Octave. I have no clue how this one is called.

Comment: @vonjd `masterrun.m` calls `runmodel.m`, where `display()` is used line 17: all this is given in the error trace from Octave. Each time, you must read the stack of errors msg (from bottom to top) to locate the problematic code. Yes, `display()` is an internal function, and is located in `/m/general/` of octave source tree. IMO, your question is purely a matter of programming so I'm inclined to migrate it to StackOverflow. I'll leave it open for some days in case someone already did the Matlab -> Octave translation.

Comment: @chl: I changed "display" to "disp" but got still the same error?!? Anyway, I think it is quite a task to port it (at least for me :-(

Comment: @chl: I think it would be a good idea to migrate it to StackOverflow - will this link still work (and reroute it there) after the migration?

Comment: As far as the results go, this has been known in computer vision at least for more than 8 years... dating back to Ivanov's use of of stochastic context-free grammars for action recognition, and subsequent development of graph-cutting techniques for detection of community structure in graphs. This is a psychology paper, and as is too often the case, the author was likely unfamiliar with prior machine learning work from other communities. In 2008, this would not be good enough to be published in any of the major vision conferences. There may be better codes available...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't look into the source code, but if you are going to convert it, these links might help:

- [Porting programs from Matlab to Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/FAQ.html#MATLAB-compatibility)
- [Differences between Octave and MATLAB](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/MATLAB_Programming/Differences_between_Octave_and_MATLAB)

Answer (score 1):

I was recently looking for an answer to the same question and found this old post. Just to add my two cents for anyone else looking...
There is an Octave library called [Missing Function Library](http://octave.sourceforge.net/missing-functions/index.html) that "*Finds functions that are in Matlab but not in Octave*". Also, there are a bunch of great packages (read "Toolboxes") for Octave as well on SourceForge. Hope this helps!